# Pebble sdk - installation and debugging issue in mac

Tags: macos, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am learning about pebble watch development. So I started with the emulator and sdk installation to learn basic "hello world" program.

Following below link

https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/

https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/hello-world/

And this link for simulator

https://github.com/Helco/PebbleLocalSim

I installed `pebble` sdk in `MAC` but when I run the

```
curl -sSL https://developer.getpebble.com/install.sh | sh && source ~/.bash_profile
```

in terminal I am getting this error

```
 Build failed! Everything installed, but building a new project doesn't work.
    Failure reason: Setting top to                           : /Users/XYZ/pebble-dev/install_test 
Setting out to                           : /Users/XYZ/pebble-dev/install_test/build 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Could not determine the compiler version ['arm-none-eabi-gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
(complete log in /Users/LinGoMac/pebble-dev/install_test/build/config.log)
[ERROR   ] The compiler/linker tools could not be found. Ensure that the arm-cs-tools directory is present in the Pebble SDK directory (/Users/XYZ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.2)
```

and a popup comes with below error asking me to send mail to pebble

```
Process:         Python [472]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Python [471]

Date/Time:       2014-06-06 14:22:53.826 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          21828 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      CA26DAE0-4D41-46C1-AC66-745E7957302C

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 1

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 181
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: iMac12,1, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.71f22
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424655302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424655302D444A2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.67.5-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 5
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

To avoid this errors I even tried manual installation but even after I had successfully installed all dependencies described in those links but I still found same error in two more scenarios

1. when I have installed all dependencies and I tried to build the "hello world" program, I faced same issue and it is not able to build the program instead it says `command build not found`

creating new project

```
pebble new-project hello_world
```

after going inside the hello_world directory, I have run the build and it throws error

```
-bash: build: command not found
```

1. Another time when I was trying to install dependencies explained [here](https://github.com/Helco/PebbleLocalSim)

I faced the issue 
**command :** `brew install SDL SDL_ttf SDL_image --universal`

**Error :**

```
Warning: sdl-1.2.15 already installed, it's just not linked
Error: You must `brew link sdl' before sdl_ttf can be installed
Error: You must `brew link sdl' before sdl_image can be installed
```

I am sure there is some problem when I am installing PYTHON and SDL for my peddle but I am  not able to get to the root of the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your system (OS X 10.7) is not compatible with the recent version of the arm-cs-tools compiler provided by the Pebble SDK. You should be able to fix this by manually downloading this [older version of arm-cs-tools here](http://assets.getpebble.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/arm-cs-tools-osx-10.7-2013-04-04.tar.bz2) and then uncompressing it in your pebble-dev folder:

```
cd ~/pebble-dev/
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/arm-cs-tools-osx-10.7-2013-04-04.tar.bz2
```

And then test the tools by running these commands:

```
export PATH=~/pebble-dev/arm-cs-tools/bin:$PATH
echo "int main(void) {return 0;}" | arm-none-eabi-gcc -x c -
```

This should give you one warning and generate a `a.out` file. If that works you are good and you can go back to your project and run `pebble build`.

Refer to [this page](https://developer.getpebble.com/1/GettingStarted/MacOS/) for the old installation instructions (SDK 1.x - Just look at the second half on installing the compiler).

If you still cannot get it to work, [CloudPebble](http://www.cloudpebble.net) is a great way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run `pebble new-project hello_world` then you've probably installed the SDK correctly.

It seems like you're trying to do `build` to build the project. You need to do `pebble build`.